# In the ROR Tutorial, rails can't find CSS files (custom.css & blueprint) or logo.png

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

In section 5.1 of the tutorial, Rails can't seem to find the CSS file (custom.css or the blueprint files) or logo.png. I have triple-checked the code and it's identical to what is in the git repository.

I have also read the [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and all the default values are correct.

I am a 100% sure that it has something to do with the asset pipeline, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is a listing of my public directory:

```
$ ls public/images public/stylesheets
public/images:
logo.png

public/stylesheets:
blueprint/  custom.cssls images stylesheets
```

Here are the errors that I'm getting:

```
Started GET "/assets/custom.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-15 14:23:20 -0800
Served asset /custom.css - 404 Not Found (14ms)

Started GET "/assets/blueprint/screen.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-15 14:23:20 -0800
Served asset /blueprint/screen.css - 404 Not Found (2ms)

Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-15 14:23:20 -0800
Served asset /logo.png - 404 Not Found (3ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Emily is pointing you in the right direction, the application is looking for the images in assets-folder, not in the public-folder. Instead of moving it out of the public folder, I would recommend to disable the asset-pipeline as long as you are dealing with the tutorial (just so you can follow the tutorial as written).

To achieve this, go into your `config/application.rb`-file and look out for the following line:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
```

and set the value to false

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

You will also have to remove/comment out `sass-rails` from your Gemfile.

After that restart your server and it should work as expected.

Once you have finished the tutorial, you should consider bending your head around the asset-pipeline, since the benefits out of it are worth the while :-)

Comment: Hi Klaffenboeck, thank you. I tried setting config.assets.enabled = false in the config/application.rb file and now my rails server won't start. I did a bundle install which had no errors, but the rake db:migrate has the same error as when I try to start the rails server. Should I post the stack trace here?

Comment: Okay, did some more searching and found the answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3246). sass-rails needs to be commented out in the Gemfile. Thanks! Everything works now.

Comment: @ppk007 : Thanks for the hint, i updated my answer. Please consider marking it as right, since it will also help people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the app is looking for your stylesheets and images in the `assets` directory instead of the `public` directory. Try moving them there, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the logo, but not for the custom.css and blueprint. If this is the right solution, the instructions in the tutorial are not correct. They should say to put the logo in the app/assets directory. I'll keep playing around with the location of the CSS files.

Comment: Okay, did some more searching and found the answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3246). sass-rails needs to be commented out in the Gemfile. Thanks! Everything works now.